# PHP generate calendar feed for Google Calendar

Tags: php, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm having trouble generating calendar feed for Google Calendar. This works fine for Office 365 (even updates the events when changed in database), but I can't make it work with Google.

When I try to import the url to Google, nothing happens, seems like it's stuck. If I reload the calendar page, I see the calendar added, but there are no events at all.

```
header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=calendar.ics');

define('DATE_ICAL', 'Ymd\THis\Z');

$eol = "\r\n";

$output = 
"BEGIN:VCALENDAR" . $eol .
"VERSION:2.0" . $eol .
"PRODID:-//CALENDAR//EVENTS//EN" . $eol .
"CALSCALE:GREGORIAN" . $eol;

// loop over events
foreach ($mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE active = 1") as $appointment):
    $output .=
    "BEGIN:VEVENT" . $eol .
    "SUMMARY:$appointment[name]" . $eol .
    "UID:$appointment[event_id]" . $eol .
    "STATUS:CONFIRMED" . $eol .
    "DTSTART:" . date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($appointment[since])) . $eol .
    "DTEND:" . date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($appointment[till])) . $eol .
    "LAST-MODIFIED:" . date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($appointment[modifiedon])) . $eol .
    "DTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd').'T'. gmdate('His') . "Z" . $eol .
    "LOCATION:$appointment[place]" . $eol .
    "GEO:" . str_replace(' ','',str_replace(',',';',$appointment[gps])) . $eol .
    "SEQUENCE:$appointment[sequence]" . $eol .
    "URL:$appointment[fb_link]" . $eol .
    "END:VEVENT" . $eol;
endforeach;

//"DESCRIPTION:" . strip_tags($appointment[sop]) . $eol .

$output .= "END:VCALENDAR";
```

Output is like this then:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//CALENDAR//EVENTS//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Some event
UID:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTSTART:20170811T180000Z
DTEND:20170812T030000Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20171206T125444Z
DTSTAMP:20180103T124514Z
LOCATION:Some address
GEO:58.049040;17.214640
SEQUENCE:1
URL:
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Also, should I provide the link to google calendar like:
a) http://somesite.com/calendar.ics
b) http://somesite.com/calendar.php
c) webcal://somesite.com/calendar.ics
?

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is the desired outcome?

Comment: I have a website where admins add events and users can comment on these etc. I want these events to be displayed in google calendar, since most users use it and it's comfortable (android etc.). So that PHP script takes information from SQL and exports it. When I connect exported ics file to outlook (using import calendar from url), all is fine, but it doesn't work with google and I don't know why.